# Does ASP.NET Boilerplate support nested multi-tenancy?

Tags: .net, multi-tenant, aspnetboilerplate

I'm currently developing a multi-tenancy SaaS.

Each tenant in our system is a subscription (think Azure subscription), where the owner of the subscription can create several stores within the subscription. They can then invite users to the subscription and grant them access to individual stores.

Sort of like this:

```
App
|- Subscription A (owned by Bob)
|  |- Store A (access granted to Alice)
|  |- Store B
|
|- Subscription B (owned by ...)
|  |- Store A'
|  |- ...
|- ...
```

What we need is that *Bob* can invite *Alice* to his subscription and the grant her access to *Store A*. *Alice* must not have access to *Store B*.

My understanding of ABP is that I can implement the subscriptions using the built-in multi-tenancy model. But what I don't understand is how can I could extend this to the store level?

Can we somehow combine organizational units with the multi-tenancy model to make this work? In our model the subscriptions contain all the billing information and the stores would most likely represent (sub-)departments.

**Edit**: I know that organizational units touch on this scenario, but then we would have to implement all filtering ourselves. Also, if we wanted to attach further permissions to certain stores, e.g. Alice is store-admin of Store A, could we leverage the built-in permission model without many "manual" checks?

Comment: ABP filters OU data automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Stores, departments or any other unit can be represented in ABP with organization unit.

> Organization units (OU) can be used to hierarchically group users and
>   entities. An OU is represented by the OrganizationUnit entity.
>   Fundamental properties of this entity are;

```
TenantId: Tenant's Id of this OU. Can be null for host OUs.
ParentId: Parent OU's Id. Can be null if this is a root OU.
Code: A hierarchical string code that is unique for a tenant.
DisplayName: Shown name of the OU.
```

For further information

https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/Organization-Units

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I edited my question to explain why I feel that OUs don't fully solve my problem.